# Stored procedure doesn't show code in database

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

I am having a weird problem. I have created a stored procedure and executed it successfully.

But when I try to look for it in the database, it doesn't show the code inside the procedure. I mean if I right click and say modify to see my procedure's code, it shows only following code :

```
set ANSI_NULLS ON
set QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
go

ALTER PROCEDURE Proc_Name
```

Why its not showing the complete code? I deleted the procedure from database and again executed then it says "There is already an object named 'Proc_Name'in the database." and it shows the same code.

Comment: What **should** the definition be (next few lines)

Comment: Are you sure you are looking at the right database? Are you creating the sproc in one database but looking in another?

Comment: Hi @Oded, Yes i am creating proc in right database and i am looking in right database. Hi @Martin i didnt get your question. are you taling about the code?

Comment: @Martin wants to know the full definition of the stored procedure. It's been cut off.

Comment: @Programmer - Yes. What does the full header of the stored procedure look like after the text gets truncated? [For example there is an issue with nested comments](https://connect.microsoft.com/SQLServer/feedback/details/178866/syntax-error-in-textheader-of-storedprocedure) - Not sure if it would cause the same behaviour you are getting.

Comment: hmm, I had a simplistic answer (proc executes fine because it's empty, doesn't do anything), but that would include "AS" in your modify window...

Comment: Hi @Martin, i got it. i just put ALTER PROC and executed it again. i can see my proc in database now. Thanks for your help though.

Comment: @Programmer: I restored the original question, because it seemed like you messed it up by mistake.

Answer (score 1):

If right-click - Modify does not show the text of the stored procedure, try the following:

```
SELECT text 
FROM syscomments 
WHERE id = (SELECT id FROM sysobjects WHERE name = 'proc_name')
```

Replace proc_name with the name of the stored procedure in question.

If that works, I would think about re-creating it using a standard template, like the one you get when you right-click Stored Procedures - New Stored Procedure, and cleaning up any odd formatting.

Comment: under what circumstances would the syscomments contain the data, but SSMS not display it? Surely SSMS uses syscomments internally?

Comment: My thought was that SSMS may get the text from syscomments, then perform formatting on it to make it look pretty, and in the formatting somehow the text may be being truncated or otherwise rendered unreadable.

Comment: @Martin has fixed his issue, so I guess we'll never know :)

Comment: @gemCer yes your answer is useful for retrieving text for procedure .....i learn new thing thanks

Answer (score 1):

```
  use <Database name>
    go
    sp_helptext <procname>
```

or else find the procedure

```
select * from sys.objects where name like '%<Procedure_name>%' and type='P'
```

Answer (score 0):

maybe the proc was created with the "WITH ENCRYPTION" tag to intentionally hide the code. Another possibility is that someone else is the owner of the object and you dont have permission to access its code.